# why pdf image is blank when compiling with xelatex?

Tags: graphics, xetex

Here is my [pdf image file you can download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4WA9GK6t9DNmhFQUpwLXkzUmc/view), and below is minimal example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{42}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I compiled it with Pdflatex, everything is fine. However, if I compile it with XeLatex, image is just blank! What is wrong? Is this pdf image file broken? Or it is the problem of xelatex?

Comment: your file works for me with xelatex in texlive 2016

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, mine is Texlive2015

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are using an old version of xdvipdfmx.
In the old xdvipdfmx, PDF files, which are newer than
version 1.5, are denied to include. The version of 42.pdf
is 1.7. A workaround is

```
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -q -E -V 7" test.tex
```

The xdvipdfmx in TeX Live 2016 tries to include PDF
files even if the version is newer than 1.5.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense. I use lower version of pdf image, it works